# RavenDb sharding with dynamic amount of servers

Tags: azure, ravendb

The typical sharding configuration looks like this:

```
            var shards = new Dictionary<string, IDocumentStore>
            {
                {"Asia", new DocumentStore {Url = "http://localhost:8080"}},
                {"Middle East", new DocumentStore {Url = "http://localhost:8081"}},
                {"America", new DocumentStore {Url = "http://localhost:8082"}},
            };
```

So we have to know what our servers are beforehand. But what if I want to use Azure scaling and so have a new Virtual Machine created automatically when it is needed. Is there any way to make a new machine be autodiscovered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, see this:
http://ayende.com/blog/4719/data-roles-dont-scale-up-down-dynamically

Second, just create a new ShardedDocumentStore and use that.